# Why can't I process the returned HTTP status codes from $.ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-app-engine

I have next JSP page that works on Google App Engine:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=windows-1251" language="java" %>
<%@ page import="com.wedding.Register" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
        <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

        <script src="js/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function submitMyForm(button) {
            var myForm = $(button).closest('form');
            $.ajax({
                url: $(myForm).attr('action'),
                type: "post",
                contentType:attr("enctype", "multipart/form-data"),
                data: $(myForm).serialize(),
                statusCode: {
                    400: function () {
                        $('.form-inline').after("<h1>400!</h1>");
                    },
                    200: function () {
                        $('.form-inline').after("<h1>200!</h1>");
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">

    <% 
        String companyName = Register.getLoggedInCompanyName(request);
        if (companyName == null) {
    %>

        <div class="navbar">
          <div class="navbar-inner">
            <a class="brand" href="#">Menu</a>
            <ul class="nav">
              <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
              <li class="active"><a href="/reg.jsp">Register</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="hero-unit">
            <h1>Login</h1>
            <p>Enter login credentials</p>
            <p>
                  <form action="/reg?action=login" class="form-inline" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                      <input type="text" name="email" class="input-xlarge" placeholder="">
                      <input type="password" name="password" class="input-xlarge" placeholder="">
                      <button type="submit" class="btn" onClick="submitMyForm(this)">Login</button>
                  </form>
            </p>
        </div>

    <% 
        } else {
    %>

        <div class="navbar">
          <div class="navbar-inner">
            <a class="brand" href="#">Menu</a>
            <ul class="nav">
              <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
              <li class="active"><a href="/reg?action=logout">Logout</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="hero-unit">
            <h1>Error</h1>
            <p>Error.</p>
        </div>

    <% 
        }
    %>

    </div>

    <div id="footer">
        <div class="container">
            <p class="muted credit"></p>
        </div>
    </div>  
</body>
```

The problem is that when a click  button the form is sent to the server but if the server return 400 HTTP status code

```
$('.form-inline').after("<h1>400!</h1>");
```

is not invoked.

I've also tried success/error function and other HTTP codes but without success. The interesting thing is that it worked once and then always fails. Instead of adding new element to HTML the browser is redirected to the generated error page.

The status code is returned using

```
HttpServletResponse.sendError(400);
```

I've checked that a correct request and response are sent. I've also checked that the latest jquery is linked.

Comment: I can't see how you are stopping the form submission. Or, did you miss that part in your snippet?

Comment: What do you mean by "stopping the form submission"? Sorry, I'm new to JS. I've tried a lot of samples but none works for me.

Comment: I went over this in my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `<button/>` enclosed in a `<form/>`, by default, submits it. So, you need to stop the form submission.

In the following example I will stick with jQuery instead of your mix of JavaScript and jQuery.

```
/* Bind the submit event */
$("form").submit(function() {
  /* Request an HTTP 400 */
  $.ajax({
    url: "http://httpstat.us/400",
    statusCode: {
      400: function() {
        console.log("HTTP 400 received");
      }
    }
  });
  /* stop the form submission */
  return false;
});​
```

```
<form action="/reg?action=login" class="form-inline" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  ...
  <button type="submit" class="btn">Login</button>
  ...
</form>
```

Since `$.ajax` is executed asynchronously, if you don't stop the form submission the browser will still submit it hence redirecting the page.

[Feel free to test it out](http://jsfiddle.net/Tpspn/).

Comment: Thanks. The problem was in contentType:attr("enctype", "multipart/form-data") line that didn't work for some reason. You solution works great without it :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried surrounding the function submitMyForm(button) around jquery document ready?

```
$(document).ready(function(){

function submitMyForm(button) {
            var myForm = $(button).closest('form');
            $.ajax({
                url: $(myForm).attr('action'),
                type: "post",
                contentType:attr("enctype", "multipart/form-data"),
                data: $(myForm).serialize(),
                statusCode: {
                    400: function () {
                        $('.form-inline').after("<h1>400!</h1>");
                    },
                    200: function () {
                        $('.form-inline').after("<h1>200!</h1>");
                    }
                }
            });
        }


});
```

Comment: That will put it out of scope for the event handler function and prevent it being called.